# winapi C++ Handling Focus

Tags: c++, winapi, setfocus, wndproc

I am working on a C++ winapi app and I am struggling to get `SetFocus()` to work for me. I create the Main window with `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE` and then within that I create its children (a couple of buttons and the beginnings of my own version of an Edit control) with `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE`, which are all working fine except for the issue of focus.

In my searches I have battled to find much in terms of how you should handle Focus. When the windows are all created they individually receive the `WM_SETFOCUS` message and I handle this message in my edit control by creaing the caret, however it seems the children never receive the `WM_KILLFOCUS` message and so caret is never destroyed.

This is now where my problem comes in: I would like the main parent window to initially have focus and for there to be no caret in my edit control and then when the child Edit control is clicked for it have focus and then when the main window is clicked it should then have focus again and so on.

So my initial thought was to use `SetFocus()` to set focus to Main Window when handling the `WM_CREATE` message however that didn't seem to work: the child don't received the `WM_KILLFOCUS` message.

My next thought was that maybe the parent has to handle passing down `WM_KILLFOCUS` to the appropriate children so I wrote a method to do that for me but the children still did not receive the `WM_KILLFOCUS` message.

So my best guess is that I am not handling the Messages correctly in my WndProc.

I have created my own Window class and distribute the messages to the appropriate classes through the following WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CBaseWindow::stWinMsgHandler(
    HWND hwnd, 
    UINT uMsg, 
    WPARAM wParam,  
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    CBaseWindow* pWnd;

    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {       
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (long)((LPCREATESTRUCT(lParam))->lpCreateParams));
    }

    pWnd = GetObjectFromWindow(hwnd);

    if (pWnd)
        return pWnd->WinMsgHandler(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
 }
```

Then each class has its own WndProc where I handle the messages as they come in.

So does anyone have any thoughts for me?

If I am going about this is complete wrong way or if I am not following best practice please say so, I am doing this to learn so shoot away.

[UPDATE]

OK here is some code to demonstrate the problem:

### Main.cpp

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include "MainWnd.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance, 
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
    int nCmdShow)
{       
    MainWnd wnd(hInstance);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0)
    {       
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

### BaseWindow.cpp

```
 #include "BaseWindow.h"

 //...

 LRESULT CALLBACK CBaseWindow::stWinMsgHandler(
       HWND hwnd, 
       UINT uMsg, 
       WPARAM wParam, 
       LPARAM lParam)
 {
       CBaseWindow* pWnd;

       if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
       {        
             SetWindowLong(hwnd, 
                  GWL_USERDATA, 
                  (long)((LPCREATESTRUCT(lParam))->lpCreateParams));
   }

        pWnd = GetObjectFromWindow(hwnd);

       if (pWnd)
             return pWnd->WinMsgHandler(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
       else
             return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
 }

 BOOL CBaseWindow::Create(DWORD dwStyles, RECT* rect)
 {  
      m_hwnd = CreateWindow(        
           szClassName, 
           szWindowTitle, 
           dwStyles, 
           rect->left, 
           rect->top, 
           rect->right - rect->left, 
           rect->bottom - rect->top, 
           NULL, 
           NULL, 
           hInstance, 
           (void *)this);   

     return (m_hwnd != NULL);
 }
```

### MainWnd.cpp

```
#include "MainWnd.h"
#define WIDTH 400
#define HEIGHT 400

MainWnd::MainWnd(HINSTANCE hInst): CBaseWindow(hInst), hInstance(hInst)
{
     SetWindowTitle(_T("Main Window"));

     WNDCLASSEX wcx;
     FillWindowClass(&wcx);                 

     if(RegisterWindow(&wcx))
     {      
         RECT rc;
     BuildRect(&rc);

         if(Create(WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, &rc))
         {          
               customTextBox = new CustomTextBox(hInst, m_hwnd);            
         }
     }  
 }

 void MainWnd::FillWindowClass(WNDCLASSEX *wcx)
 {
      wcx->cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
      wcx->style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DROPSHADOW;                     
      wcx->lpfnWndProc = CBaseWindow::stWinMsgHandler;          
      wcx->cbClsExtra = 0;                                      
      wcx->cbWndExtra = 0;                                      
      wcx->hInstance = hInstance;                                   
      wcx->hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);             
      wcx->hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
      wcx->hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));      
      wcx->lpszMenuName = NULL;                                 
      wcx->lpszClassName = _T("MainWindow");
      wcx->hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
 }

 LRESULT CALLBACK MainWnd::WinMsgHandler(
       HWND hwnd, 
       UINT uMsg, 
       WPARAM wParam, 
       LPARAM lParam)
 {          
       switch (uMsg)
       {
       case WM_DESTROY:
            delete customTextBox;
            PostQuitMessage(0);     
            break;
       case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            SetFocus(hwnd);
            break;
       default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
       }
       return 0;
 }
```

### CustomTextBox.cpp

```
 #include "CustomTextBox.h"

 CustomTextBox::CustomTextBox(
      HINSTANCE hInst, 
      HWND hParent): CBaseWindow(hInst), 
                 hParent(hParent),
 {  
      WNDCLASSEX wcx;
      CreateWndClassEX(wcx);
      if(RegisterWindow(&wcx))
      {
           RECT clientRect;
           CreateClientRect(clientRect);
           CreateChild(WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP, &clientRect, hParent);       
      }
 }

 void CustomTextBox::CreateWndClassEX(WNDCLASSEX& wcx)
 {
      wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
      wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;    
      wcx.lpfnWndProc = CBaseWindow::stWinMsgHandler;
      wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;                                           
      wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
      wcx.hInstance = hInstance;
      wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
      wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
      wcx.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
      wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
      wcx.lpszClassName = _T("Edit Control");
      wcx.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
 }

 LRESULT CALLBACK CustomTextBox::WinMsgHandler(
      HWND hwnd, 
      UINT uMsg, 
      WPARAM wParam, 
      LPARAM lParam)
 {
      switch(uMsg)
      {
      /* Handling the caret */
      case WM_SETFOCUS:
           CreateCaret(hwnd, NULL, 0, nWindowY); 
           SetCaretPos(GetEndOfLinePoint(), nCaretPosY * nCharY); 
           ShowCaret(hwnd); 
           return 0;    
      case WM_MOUSEACTIVATE:
           SetFocus(hwnd);
           return MA_ACTIVATE;
      case WM_KILLFOCUS:
           DestroyCaret();
           return 0;
      default:
           return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
      }         
 }
```

### Discovery

In writing up this code I came across one of the causes of my problems: in my actual application I don't have a title bar and so to move the window I was sending `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` to my main window on `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`:

`SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, NULL);`

I then had my `SetFocus()` after this and this wasn't working but if I switch them around and handle the `SetFocus()` first then the clicking does change focus.

There is still a problem with initially setting the focus though. At the moment after starting the app the custom edit control still displays the caret even though it doesn't have focus and you need to click on it to give it focus, whereby it will receive keyboard input. After that the focus works as desired: if I click on the main window it has focus; if I click on the custom edit, it has focus etc.

Comment: Please post a self contained example demonstrating the problem. WM_KILLFOCUS is always sent to window when it's about to loose focus. so there might something wrong in your code. Another thing - did you try to add WS_TABSTOP style to your child window?

Comment: Try to remove ALL your focus specific (added) code from your test application and see how/if focus works by default. If it works, then it seems you do some excessive things that either block normal focus processing or do it twice in a row - that is you focus just unfocused control and vice versa. If it does not work, then you created either your parent window or controls in a wrong way.

Comment: @aleguna I have posted code that describes my problem and I have added `WS_TABSTOP` to the child but it still doesn't work fully.

@Stan I tried to remove all focus specific code and it still didn't quite work. If you read my update above you will see pretty much all my code. Hopefully we can work out where my errors are.

Thanks for the help

Comment: OK I have sorted out the moving the window and the getting focus on click problem. It is only now setting the focus initially that is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so it turns out that my entire problem lied with that line `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, NULL);` Once I switched this:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:                        
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, NULL);       
    SetFocus(hwnd);
break;
```

to:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:                        
    SetFocus(hwnd);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, NULL);
break;
```

everything came together.